# Unable to check out using TortoiseSVN - "File already exists" error for two files in repository

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

When I try to check out the head version of a large repository, it fails on two particular files:

```
Error | Failed to run the WC DB work queue associated with
Error | 'C:\Work\gpss_src\cpp\apps\RTRover\lib', work item 6625 (file-install
Error | cpp/apps/RTRover/lib/prn.h 1 0 1 1)
Error | Can't move 'C:\Work\gpss_src\.svn\tmp\svn-F3F9679B' to
Error | 'C:\Work\gpss_src\cpp\apps\RTRover\lib\prn.h': Cannot create a file when that
Error | file already exists.
```

I've found similar problems posted, but not this exact issue. There is not an issue with case--there really is only a single prn.h file in the entire repository regardless of case. I get the same error with prn.cpp if I use `svn move` to rename prn.h.

The only solution I've found so far is to use `svn move` to rename prn.h and prn.cpp, but I would prefer to not rename the files. I've also tried renaming the original files and adding an empty prn.h, but that also causes this error. If I rename the original files and don't create a dummy prn.h or prn.cpp, everything will checkout without any errors. I also do not have any problems checking out the source in a Linux environment.

My guess is there is either a problem with the repository's SVN database or perhaps there's a version incompatibility. The SVN server is using version 1.6.11. The client is using [TortoiseSVN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TortoiseSVN) 1.8.5 which is linked against SVN version 1.8.8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have a file named `prn.*` on Windows. There are certain *reserved names* on Windows:

- `PRN`
- `CON`
- `AUX`
- `NUL`
- `LPT1/2/3/4`
- `CLOCK$`

Files with those names, no matter what the suffix can not be created on a Windows system. You'll usually get some funky error such as *Wrong number of Parameter* or *Read only file* or *File already exists*.

You can prove it by doing this:

```
C:> notepad test.txt
C:> move test.txt prn.txt
The parameter is incorrect.
```

Unfortunately, there are no other solutions except to use another OS. Even Cygwin won't save you in this case.

Comment: Great, thanks! It looks like it would work with cygwin apps, but not native Win32 apps (since cygwin version 1.70): http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-specialnames.html But I'll rename the files to save myself trouble in the future.

Comment: Good to know that Cygwin gets around these issues now. I'm surprised I didn't know this since 1.7 was released around 2009.