# Error when checking out project from svn

Tags: svn

Hello I am trying to check out a project from SVN hosted at google code and I am getting the following error:

```
Failed to run the WC DB work queue associated with 'C:\Users\Pedro\workspace\de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.coreasl\de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.syntax-asl\src\main\java\de\tudarmstadt\ukp\dkpro\core\api\syntax\type\constituent',  
work item 190 (file-install 125 de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.syntaxasl/src/main/java/de/tudarmstadt/ukp/dkpro/core/api/syntax/type/constituent/PRN.java 1 0 1 1)
Can't move'C:\Users\Pedro\workspace\de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core-asl\.svn\tmp\svn-B2124D53' to 'C:\Users\Pedro\workspace\de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.coreasl\de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.syntax-asl\src\main\java\de\tudarmstadt\ukp\dkpro\core\api\syntax\type\constituent\PRN.java':
Não é possível criar um arquivo já existente.
```

The last sentence is in Portuguese, and it says "It is not possible to create an existing file." Any help?

Comment: Can you give us more information? What are you doing in order to checkout? What client are you using? What is the protocol of the server?

Comment: Sure, and sorry for the late response. Client: I tried TortoiseSVN and also Subclipse. The protocol: https.

Comment: Are the files on your Subversion server "owned" by the user who runs Subversion? Sometimes, a directory on the Subversion server has the wrong permission set.

Comment: I don't know if I can actually check that information since the subversion server is offered by google code... I am trying to do an anonymous checkout, I can try to check out with the user that I make my commits, to see if it works out.

Comment: Subversion on Google Code uses version 1.6 of the Subversion server -- a bit behind, but not too bad. Should work with 1.7 and 1.8 clients. However, I did notice this in the [FAQ](https://code.google.com/p/support/wiki/SubversionFAQ#What_version_of_Subversion_do_you_use?): _Anonymous checkouts can be done via `http://`, while developers must use authenticated `https://` to commit changes._ Are you using `http` and not `https`?`

Comment: I am using https. Tried to check out using authenticated https:// and the same error occurs. My subversion client version is 1.8.8.

Comment: And I am trying to checkout on Windows 7

Comment: Found the reason... the problem is that there is a file named "PRN.java": http://stackoverflow.com/a/22771580/1477268

Comment: Yes. That'll do it. You can't have files named `con.*`, `prn.*`, `com[1-9].*`, `nul.*`, `aux.*`, and `lpr[1-9].*` on Windows. You get all sorts of strange error message that has nothing to do with the illegal file name. I should have caught that PRN name in your original error message. I have a [pre-commit hook](https://github.com/qazwart/SVN-Precommit-Kitchen-Sink-Hook) that can catch these illegal names and prevent them from being added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question: The issue lies in the name of the file trying to be checked out. Windows does not allow a file to be named as "PRN.*".